# Increase typing speed?

Tags: typing

It has recently been brought to my attention that my typing skills leave much to be desired. I've been programming a few years in college now, and typing speed has never been very important. Classes do not focus on how much code you can output, but instead how to design and implement code.

Now that I have a job however, demands have changed slightly and I think it in my benefit to increase my typing skills, at least a little bit!

Do you have any suggestions for effective methods to increase typing skills?

Comment: I think this should be migrated to programmers-stackexchange.

Comment: Well, quality should beat quantity hands down regardless of what you code. As long as it's not the hunt-and-peck 10 (not counting typos) chars/minute typing...

Comment: @slandau: I don't even thing its on topic there.  We're talking about typing.  Its like asking how to drive faster safely in order to get to work as a programmer quicker.

Comment: I mean, typing is absolutely essential to ALL programming and development, right? It is something that everyone on this site is incredibly familiar with and its relation to their hobby/job/pastime. That doesn't qualify as even remotely related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer typing games that encourage you to type faster for a reward (high score). Do a search for 'typing games' and have fun. I'm about 80 wpm atm (according to some games I peak near 90 but the longer words drag my average down).

Whatever you choose, you do need to keep doing it on a regular basis.

Comment: [Typing of the dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Typing_of_the_Dead) was a fun one.

Answer (score 3):

I went through this a few years into my consulting career...I downloaded a free typing tutor program and used it every day for a month:

- 10 minutes in the morning before starting work for the day
- 10 minutes during my lunch break
- 10 minutes at the end of the day before leaving work

I found that as my typing improved it was fun to fit in a few more 10-minute sessions each day as I felt like it.

Keep up with it for a month and you'll be amazed at how much better you are at typing!

Cheers

Comment: It appears you can do this online now, with free tutors like this one: http://www.typingweb.com/

Answer (score 1):

Download a touch typing trainer and train ;-) it's actual fun until the point where you reached your limit. See http://typingsoft.com/all_typing_tutors.htm for a list.