# How can I make typing code more efficient?

Tags: coding-efficiency

I am a poor typist, I will admit. After my recent switch from a keyboard I had used for years to a slightly different one, a brief stint with Dvorak and not doing a great deal of typing for a while, I'm worse than normal! My latest tests show about 90 WPM for native language and about 50 for code. Other than practice, what are some good methods to make typing more efficient, particularly worried about my error rate?

Would it be crazy, for example, to make the home row modal, and map it to common special chars such as $"!%^&*()-+ + _ `<caps>` etc?

I use Vim, and I like to be able reduce time from thought occurring to having thought in text, so as to not interrupt my process. I also need to improve my accuracy because I tend to make a fair few errors and that could be problematic.

I have tried 10fastfingers for natural language, and it says I'm better than 95% or something like that... but 90 is optimistic, and lately it's been 80-85 or so mostly.

Comment: I think you shouldn't be so self-critical. 90 wpm is nowhere near "poor" imho.

Comment: If you use emacs a *lot*, consider a Kinesis keyboard. Otherwise, try the exercises [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393465/increase-typing-speed?rq=1) before trying to reinvent the keyboard. Remember to exercise for accuracy as well as speed.

Comment: The deadliest gunfighters of the old west were not the ones fastest on the draw, they were the ones with the best accuracy.  Similarly, typing faster will not make you a more efficient coder.  You need to write *better* code.  Don't worry about how fast you can type (You're already very nearly twice my speed).

Comment: I want to at least maintain my current speed, but improve my accuracy. My main concern was with accuracy. Though the noticeable lag between thought and text is frustrating for me, when typing native language. And I have found myself on a fair few occasions using the wrong keys and doing something stupid in vim, though that is easy to rectify and notice, I am weary of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little too broad and opinion based. That being said, as it is not a programming question, it might be better suited for [our sister site, Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

For remapping the home row, that is definitely personal preference. Go ahead if you feel you'll benefit from it. What might work for others might not work for you, just like how gamers have custom keyboard bindings that suit them and I would not make sense to use at all.

As for typing speed. If you've tried [10FastFingers](http://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english), you'll realize you're pretty fast at 90WPM, compared to the rest of the population.

As for programming, I feel the limiting factor isn't the typing speed of 50WPM, but rather the thought process. I think 50WPM for myself is more than enough to program, because I can't think as fast as I type to produce good code. Programming definitely isn't like in the movies where people mash keyboards and somehow hack NSA servers. More time is spent thinking on how to translate ideas into code than actually typing out the code.

Obligatory GIF:

[Programming in Real Life vs Movies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMRP6.jpg)

Also, for certain languages that are fairly long to write, IDEs have a ton of features that auto-correct and auto-complete. (Visual Studio for all Microsoft Languages, programmers save a ton of time with IntelliSense built in) and Sublime Text is not an IDE, but a more feature rich text editor that many people live by. There's also a ton of Vim and Emacs followers that memorize and utilize shortcuts and their fingers never have to leave the keyboard and use the mouse, if concentration and keeping the flow is an important thing to consider. [There are a ton of shortcuts that speed things up for Emacs](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/linux/Emacs_23.2.1.html) as well as [Vim](http://bullium.com/support/vim.html). And all of that is before adding in plugins.

This is all very much subjective, of course.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried 10FastFingers. . . I think their % of population is more like % of population who try 10FastFingers. Or I'm just surrounded by elite typists.

Comment: @iheanyi yeah it's everyone that plays in 24 hours. the top ones are really high though. And I understand what you mean, it's fine though, I think anything >45WPM is enough for programming

Comment: I agree with your assertion iheanyi. Its one of the most popular sources, and the average user is satisfied with 45 wpm.

Comment: Just did the 10fastfingers, got 96 words per minute, 492 keystrokes of which 12 were erroneous, 90 correct words and 2 submitted erroneous ones. Seems my main slow down is still in special chars. Though submitting two incorrect words is poor, it isn't such a common occurrence and I will not be under such time constraints...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you can expect to sustain significantly faster typing speeds while programming. Given that programming involves more thought interruption, for just raw typing speed improvements, you're better off training yourself to type at 120wpm.

I think you'd probably be better served learning or customizing your IDE's shortcuts, code completion, and other programmer helper features to suit your needs. Your typing speed may not improve but it may boost your LOC per minute rate.

Why are you trying to increase your typing speed while programming? 50wpm seems plenty fast - I can't imagine any meaningful metric being based on your code typing speed so I'm guessing you want to optimize something else and this is the approach you decided to take.